# Not sure which Connection Pool Api to use for this java/MySQL database program

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I heard jbdc has issues with multi threading access.  I've also heard boneCP recommended in another post, but I was wondering if anyone else had used another which they found easy and high performance for the asynchronous stuff

Also the Apache version said it might not work above java 1.6 and I'm using java.runtime.version: 1.7.0_07-b11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up settling on BoneCP after trying some other APIs in practice. I'm using it with Java 1.7 and it works great even in high-concurrency situations. Plus, the developers are responsive when reporting issues.

I had previously used C3P0 but it had some very strange bugs that went away after I switched to BoneCP. If you do a little bit of digging on C3P0, you'll see that it has been untouched for several years now and development just resumed. It broke at strange times in my application.

I use the `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` from the normal Mysql JDBC package. Then I just set up things as following (you can tweak the settings as you wish):

```
pbds = new BoneCPDataSource();      
pbds.setDatasourceBean(mysqlcpds);
pbds.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(1);              
pbds.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(10);    
pbds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes(60);
pbds.setIdleMaxAgeInMinutes(240);
pbds.setPartitionCount(1);
```

Then, you just get `Connection`s from this object (it is thread safe.) I use the same code from several threads; the Java 7 **try-with-resources** block is especially convenient and avoids a lot of boilerplate (no `finally` is needed and the connection is guaranteed to be closed):

```
try( Connection conn = pbds.getConnection() ) { 

    ... do stuff with conn

} catch (SQLException e) {          
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the flavor of the month API.  Does it work strange at all?  Like that one that maintained a single constant connection?

Comment: I agree, it did seem that there was no good option for a while. But I ended up sticking with BoneCP after searching for a while. Which one maintained a single connection?

Comment: Not sure.  It was mentioned in a post I read earlier today.  If I tried to search it down I'd spend 3 hours and never find it (too commonplace).  But yeah.  I'll give this a shot.  I can certainly find my own example code but if you know an excellent tutorial feel free to drop it here =D

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, added. It's very simple to use.